# HttpClient PostAsync failing on Xamarin.Forms (StatusCode: 404)

Tags: heroku, xamarin, http-post, xamarin.forms, httpclient

```
var url = "http://domain.herokuapp.com/api/createuser";
var item = new { username = "kasunrt1", email = "dgggdgdg@test.com", password = "3333", tele = "123456789" };
var uri = new Uri(url);
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(item);
var content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
var client = new HttpClient();
var result = await client.PostAsync(url, content);
```

**The service is up & running. It works on browser & postman when I manually execute the API string like below.**

http://domain.herokuapp.com/api/createuser/nameTest/testmail@gmail.com/346gf4/123456789

**Even the below code works.**

```
var result = await client.PostAsync("http://domain.herokuapp.com/api/createuser/nameTest/testmail@gmail.com/346gf4/123456789", null);
```

**The result is a 404**
*{StatusCode: 404, ReasonPhrase: 'Not Found', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
{
Server: Cowboy
Connection: keep-alive
X-Powered-By: Express
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Date: Fri, 25 Nov 2016 06:27:06 GMT
Via: 1.1 vegur
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 28
}}*

**Heroku receives only the following request.**
*2016-11-25T06:31:27.827923+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/api/createuser" host=domain.herokuapp.com request_id=1cb51340-05a5-4503-acb5-9e3b45cdf393 fwd="61.245.163.5" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=71ms status=404 bytes=226*

**I can't seem to find what's wrong here. Any help would be highly appreciated.
Thanks!**

Comment: Cannot reproduce. I get result OK with the code you provided in question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two options to send data to an API/URL. Either via url-parameter or with POST-parameter. Your url which you send with Postman sends the parmeter through the url parameter ([whats the difference?](http://www.w3schools.com/TAgs/ref_httpmethods.asp)).

And on the other side, you send the parameter via POST-parameter with the `PostAsync` method of the `HttpClient`. This values are sent in the request body, in the format that the content type specifies.

The `HttpClient` then tries to reach the url *http://domain.herokuapp.com/api/createuser* (withtout the parameters at the end), and this url doesn't exists, that's why you get the 404-error.

Option 1: Change your API-method that the values are sent via POST

Option 2: Change your request to set your values in the `url` variable

Option 1 is the preffered and right way to achive this. Because you POST something to your api. Your values needs to be in the request-body and not in the url directly. So change your API and your code should work

Comment: Yes. Option 1 worked. Thanks  a bunch for the nice explanation and the answer! @Joehl

Comment: What do you mean in option1? can you please be more specific?